# How to open a popup every 5 seconds in a website

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I needed a code which will open a popup every 5 seconds in my website.
The popup link would be same.

Comment: How do I ask a good question?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are just looking for a way to move people away from your website you could also start some music on pageload.

Comment: Nope, Just needed it for pop ads. I'm not a coder

Comment: I'm using WordPress anyways

Comment: Yep another link will do that like www.example.com/popup

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   showAlert();

    function showAlert(){
        alert("Hello");
        setTimeout(showAlert, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: He was referring to spamming popup links webpages.  "The popup link would be same."

Comment: I think He can do it using a function setTimeout()

Comment: I'm not referring to spammy popup links. It was for redirection to my partner's site with a referral id of an play store app.